# wkhtmltopdf OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: flask, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to generate a pdf in my flask application using `pdfkit`.

On localhost the application works fine without any errors, after i deployed the application on ubuntu server vps, when trying to generate pdf file it gives me this error in console:

```
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]:     self.configuration = (Configuration() if configuration is None
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]:   File "/home/userp/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pdfkit/configuration.py", line 18, in 
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]:     ['which', 'wkhtmltopdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]:   File "/home/userp/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/subprocess.py", line 585, in __
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]:     reraise(*exc_info)
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]:   File "/home/userp/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/subprocess.py", line 554, in __
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]:     restore_signals, start_new_session)
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]:   File "/home/userp/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/subprocess.py", line 1312, in _
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]:     raise child_exception
Apr 12 16:31:51 ubuntu gunicorn[18725]: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Down below inside **configuration.py** file if i tried to print out the value of `self.wkhtmltopdf` it shows the file path **/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf**:

```
if not self.wkhtmltopdf:
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        self.wkhtmltopdf = subprocess.Popen(
            ['where', 'wkhtmltopdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
    else:
        self.wkhtmltopdf = subprocess.Popen(
            ['which', 'wkhtmltopdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()

try:
    with open(self.wkhtmltopdf) as f:
        pass
except IOError:
    raise IOError('No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "%s"\n'
                    'If this file exists please check that this process can '
                    'read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - '
                    'https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf' % self.wkhtmltopdf)
```

also typing `which wkhtmltopdf` gives the same results which mean the program is already installed.

I've already installed all the necessary libraries literally as i installed them on my machine.

The most interesting thing is that, if i run the application from `python manage.py runserver` and tried to generate pdf file its get generated and no errors appears , but from gunicorn and nginx the errors shows up !!!!!

I've tried everything to make that work, i've also seen a lots of articles where they talking about this problem but without avail !!!!

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely to be not being able to run wkhtmltopdf in a headless state in your server vps.

Do have a look at https://pypi.org/project/headless-pdfkit/0.1.1/#files

This additionally requires xvfb installed, which will wrap the wkhtmltopdf command with a /bin/bash\nxvfb-run before executing.